# How to search and replace 2 lines (together) in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, editor, replace

I would like to search multiple files via eclipse for the following 2 lines:

```
@Length(max = L_255)
private String description;
```

and replace them with these two:

```
@Length(max = L_255, message="{validator.description.len}")
private String description;
```

Comment: made the line as code to show that it is on 2 lines. CTRL+H doesn't let me add 2 lines for search and replacement

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Search are multi-line by default in Eclipse when you are using regex:

```
(\@Length\(max = L_255)\)([\r\n\s]+private)
```

> I would like to add "private String description;"

```
(\@Length\(max = L_255)\)([\r\n\s]+private\s+?String\s+description\s*?;)
```

replaced by:

```
\1, message="{validator.description.len}")\2
```

It works perfectly in a File Search triggered by a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>.

[image: Eclipse multi-line search]

As mentioned in [Tika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348901/tika)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14363866/6309), you can **directly copy the two lines selected in the "Containing Text" field**: those lines will be **converted as a regexp** for you by Eclipse.

Comment: I would like to add "private String description;" also as part of my search since the @Length(max = L_255) line is also present for other fields like "private String name". So the above suggestion will not work.

Comment: I am trying to search multiple successive lines.

Comment: @Samuel: picture added, answer updated to take your full line into account. It will work for multiple successive lines. Give it a try.

Answer (score 67):

Another tip on how to get the regex for a selected block. 
Open one of the files that contains the multiple lines (multiline) to search or replace.
Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and select "Regular expression". Close the Find/Replace window.
Select the block you need and click again <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Find/Replace window.
Now in the Find text box you have the regular expression that exactly matches your selection block.

(I discovered this, only after creating manually a regexp for very long block :)

Comment: Excellent tip! Thanks, you saved me a lot of time figuring out how to build my regex.

Comment: You can use this trick to build the regex to copy into a file search as well. Huge time saver, thank you!

Comment: This is really a cool function though it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Not all superheroes wear capes. That's why I didn't see one.

Answer (score 20):

CTRL+H does take two lines if you use regexp (and you don't have to write the regexp by yourself, eclipse does that for you).

1. Select your lines.
2. Click CTRL+H. The search dialog opens up.
   If "Regular expression" is already checked, eclipse will have converted the two lines you search for into regexp for you, click Search.
   If "Regular expression" if not already checked", check it and click Cancel (eclipse remembers your choice).
3. Select your lines again.
4. Click CTRL+H. The search dialog opens up. This time "Regular expression" is already selected. eclipse will have converted the two lines you search for into regexp for you, click Search.

Comment: I like your description of the solution best, simple and fast and foolproof. Thnx!

Comment: 2nd line is hidden gem feature..Thanksss

Comment: Very very thanks. I was not familiar with this eclipse feature. I was going crazy building regexes into Find\Replace.

Answer (score 4):

A quick tip for including multiple lines as part of a manually constructed regular expression:

Where you would normally use `.*` to match any character zero or more times, instead consider using something like `(?:.|\r?\n)*`. Or put an extra `?` at the end to make it non-greedy.

***Explanation***: `.` doesn't match new lines so need to do an "either-or": The parentheses match either the `.` before the pipe or the new line after it. The `?` after `\r` makes the carriage return before the line feed optional to allow Windows or Unix new lines. The `?:` excludes the whole thing as a capturing group (which helps to avoid a stack overflow).

Comment: When I try this in Eclipse (4.5) as: `publisher(?:.|\r?\n)*` it shows an error in the dialog "Find pattern too complex"

Edit: adding the question mark to the end as: `publisher(?:.|\r?\n)*?` makes it work! Thanks for the tip and regex explanation.

Comment: There are certain cases where if I add too many characters in the second word I want to search I still see the "Find pattern too complex" error. So `publisher(?:.|\r?\n)*?id` works but `publisher(?:.|\r?\n)*?identification` displays the error

Answer (score 3):

Click Ctrl + F and select "Regular Expression" and then search the lines. In case to perform the same on multiple files, click Ctrl + H, click on 'File Search' and perform the same.

Answer (score 0):

Select the folder that contains all your files and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: Do the lines separately? Or try a multiline regular expression.

Comment: I can't do it separately since it might affect other fields. I wasn't able to figure out the multiline expression which will correctly identify the above 2 lines, hence the question.