# eclipse keyboard shorcut list/poster

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I am trying to locate a list of shorcuts so I can print it and learn a couple every day till I master not using the mouse.

I know about [Eclipse Shortcut Overview](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/EclipseEmacsKeybindings_3_1.pdf) but this is using emacs bindings, and I am using the default shorcuts.

I am not looking for an blogpost mentioning 10 nice shorcuts, I want a comprehensive list (maybe not complete but near, whatever fits in one page printout)

I am using eclipse 3.6 on windows but a list of 3.5 etc would help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Preferences > General > Keys

you got them all (dunno about EMAC ..)
and - but - can export them to csv !

Comment: I had done that before, but when I try it in my 3.6 I get a NPE: !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2010-11-05 13:55:45.808
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.model.KeyController$7.run(KeyController.java:538)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.model.KeyController.exportCSV(KeyController.java:556)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.NewKeysPreferencePage$2.widgetSelected(NewKeysPreferencePage.java:606)
 at

Answer (score 1):

I always found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> the only *first* shortcut I needed to know with Eclipse.

Wherever you are, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, and the list of all shortcuts available to you **given the current context** will pop-up.

[image]

See [this article](http://www.pleso.net/en/publications/2008/03/24/eclipse-hotkeys/) for reference.