# How to search for a method or variable name within android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, search

from a relative newcomer, can anyone tell me how to do a method or variable name search inside eclipse when working on a large project? Sometimes I feel lost when starting something new in a team.

Comment: You can search for text within a project ([see this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175035/eclipse-find-in-project)). I'm not sure if that allows you to specify what you are searching for though (i.e. variable or method name) but it's worth checking out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. In Eclipse, Select menu `Search` and again `Search`.

In Tab `Java Search` you can select what you are looking for (i.e method, type, package, field, ...) and where to search.

Regards.

Comment: is there a way to search for local variables (in functions and blocks) with a specific name?