# Search for every mention of a variable in a file

Tags: c, editor, sublimetext2, notepad++, sublimetext

I have a massive file, of length more than 4000 lines. There are more than 200 variables declared, and some of the variables are really badly defined: For example,

```
int s;
int waste;
```

Now, I need some tool that helps me find every mention of the variable `s`. I can't use `ctrl+F` because that would give me every mention of the letter `s`, rather than every mention of the variable `s`. So, `s` would get detected in `waste` as well.

For example, when I search for `s`, I want this to get detected:

```
if(abc == 2 && s == 3)
```

But this should not be detected:

```
if(abc == 2 && waste == 3)
```

I'm currently using `Notepad++`, and would like to know if there's any feature on `Notepad++` that would allow me to do this.

If not, can you suggest any other editor / tool / software that would do this for me?

If I have something like:

```
int x;
struct a
{
    int x;
    int y;
} st;
```

And I wan't to find only all occurrences of the `x` declared outside the `struct`, then the `ctrl+F match whole word` feature of `Notepad++` would not work, because even `st->x` would be matched.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this in **vim**

`/\<your-query\>`

And if you want to replace every occurrence of the word `foo` with `bar` then

`:%s/\<foo\>/bar/g`

using `\<` and `\>` around the word matches only the complete word.

**EDIT:**

- Move the cursor inside the block you want to preserve.
- Use `di{` to kill the block to a temporary register.
- Use `:%s/\<foo\>/bar/g` to replace every occurrence of "foo" with "bar"
- Press ``` `` ``` to go to the last edited position.
- Press `P` to yank the text back inside the braces

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, @Lakshay. But there are a few scenarios that that would not match. I edited the question after reading your solution, as I realized I hadn't been as clear as I should have been.
Please let me know if you have any other method of solving this problem.

Comment: @RandomlyNamedUser You could do this by temporarily moving the part that you want to remain unchanged to a register. This can be done in vim using `di{` to select the part inside the braces. Then repeat the above command and then paste the part that was deleted back to its location.

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad++, press Ctrl+F, check the "Match whole word only" checkbox and click "Find" or "Find All in Current Document". I'm using Notepad++ v6.2.2 (UNICODE). I tried the scenario you presented in your question and using this approach worked for me.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much @bookhuntress. But there are a few scenarios that that would not match. I edited the question after reading your solution, as I realized I hadn't been as clear as I should have been.

Comment: In Eclipse, users can highlight a variable and press Ctrl+Shift+G to search for all occurrences of this variable. Search results will appear inside the Search tab at the bottom. You can also try this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521485/how-to-search-for-a-method-or-variable-name-within-android-project). I have tried these approaches using Eclipse for Java, but I think there's also an Eclipse version for C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

on [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) place the cursor on your variable (don't select it) and press Command + D multiple times until it has added a cursor in front of every match then you can edit the variable and press ESC to exit the multi-cursor mode.