# How to search for a string in my entire project in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, string, project

I need to find a string, but it is too time-consuming to Ctrl+F every class. Is there a faster way to search the entire project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse find in project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175035/eclipse-find-in-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the String and `Control+Alt+G` in Eclipse (Windows).
2. Use the Search Window, to open it `Control+H` in Eclipse(Windows).

Comment: Or in the menu: Search -> File... -> Search after you've setup the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Much better than `Control+H` that may takes ages in Eclipse is to install a full text search plugin like Quick Search from Spring Tools or instaSearch. It will increase your productivity immensely.

Check out this blog post:

http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/04/03/use-eclipse-quick-search-plugin-for-faster-text-searches/

Answer (score 0):

You can search for specific string using `ctrl` + `H`, choose 'File search' tab.

But if you want search any string, try use a regular expression at 'Containing text' `".+"`.

If you're trying search string in java code, regular expression above will match strings used at annotations. To avoid this try this one `^\s*?[^@]\w*?".+".*$`