# Android Voice Recording

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest

I'm trying to develop an android app that needs a user to record his voice.
I was following the Dev guide on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Eclipse gives me this error in my manifest file

```
The prefix "adroid" for attribute "adroid:name" associated with an element type "uses-     permission" is not bound.`
```

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.rectest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.rectest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

  </manifest>
```

Comment: Look like android is spelled wrong somewhere in the project in an xml file, but in that file I don't see any mistakes. Check all of your XML files for any spelling mistakes. If you can't find any, try cleaning the project in Eclipse and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: You can do a recursive search on the whole project on the term `adroid` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175035/eclipse-find-in-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you had a typo error when you first wrote the code.

```
`The prefix "adroid" for attribute "adroid:name" associated with an element type "uses-       permission" is not bound`.`
```

As it should have been "android" and not "adroid".
The code you attached looks fine, so you should try to Clean and re-build your project.
Go to Project -> Clean -> Select your project. If this keeps, try to restart your eclipse.

[image]