# Creating a new project in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, project, eclipse-cdt

Hi i am wondering what is a complete proces of creating a new project in eclipse, so you can start writting your code. When i create a new c project, i enter its name click finish but then i cant start writing since the area where you should write is still dark. It look like that: 
[image]

I have created a new c project and this is what comes up.

Comment: Voted to migrate this to superuser as it has nothing to do with programming. Also, on superuser, the user might get some help on software.

Comment: Can the upvoter please explain? I am not telling to vote this question down, as it might be of some use for future readers on superuser, but by upvoting, you are encouraging users to ask questions on the wrong site!

Comment: @AshishAhuja Issues with tools used to develop code are on topic for Stack Overflow (but I don't think the question deserves an up vote).

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175035/eclipse-find-in-project, is this a good reason? And also: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4836/what-is-the-difference-between-super-user-and-stack-overflow . So being strict, I think that it has more to do with SO than SU.

Comment: @greg-449, yeah but this has nothing to do with programming. SU is made for software problems, while, SO is made for programming problems. Also, see the comment I have posted below.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri, you can see the comment I posted above. Also, SO is meant only for programming problems, not problems for software that is used for programming,

Comment: @AshishAhuja Given that SU is meant for "computer hardware & software enthusiasts and power users", someone that wants to be as strict as you, could ask to remove such a question from "SU". The real question is: why do you think it is so important to be so strict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the project on the left panel, you will be able to see its content and a c file on which you can simply click to make it appear on the editing panel.

If your project is empty, you can fill it by adding a new C source file, with the help of the `File` main menu.

Comment: Ask another question if you have problem with some code. This code is the standard minimal test code that prints "Hello world!" on the console. Build the project and run it. After that you will be sure that your environment is correctly installed. Then you can start to learn and write code...

Comment: Well on that code, it sais that prinf could not be resolved. Why is that

Comment: Post another question, please, on SO you need to open a new question for every new question. But, search for such a problem first, somebody may encountered the same previously...

Comment: Huh it sucks because i have to wait for 90 minutes.