# Finding the location of function name in eclipse ide

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to java world.
I am working on ECLIPSE IDE. I have a function name that i need to use but i am not able to find in which class it is written.
How can i get this information
Can some one help me out here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175035/does-a-find-in-project-feature-exist-in-eclipse-ide?rq=1

Comment: Hover on function / method name and then `ctrl+click`.

Comment: I guess you mean method, not function (in the Java/00 world a class has fields and methods): _Search > Java_: enter the method name and for _Search for_ choose _Method_.

Answer (score 0):

When you are coding in Eclipse, press CTRL and click on any core Java class/Custom Class/Methods name in your source. You will be taken to the source.
Eclipse will now show a screen saying you don't have the sources installed if you are trying to access a code for which you don't have source. However, in this screen there will be a link saying "Attach source...". Click that link and import the src.zip file from your JDK installation directory (src.zip).
*Use JDK in development environment not JRE*, this is good for learning

Comment: Thanks for the reply friend. But my problem is i don't know from where this function is getting called. All i have is that i need to use this function. But when try using it i am getting error message - undefined function. How do i go to the location where the function is Implemented

Comment: @ayyer you are getting undefined because you have not imported the function in your class file. After importing you will be able to go to source by following above answer

Comment: yes. But my problem is i don't know which class to import. IS there any mechanism in eclipse to search for the function's class in entire project using function name