# Eclipse To replace two same line

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

By mistakenly i have replace couple of line in all the java files by using global replace (CTRL + H) function. 
as currently text is as below :-

```
data.creationtime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.creationtime);
data.creationtime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.creationtime);
```

and i want to replace last line with correct word as below :-

```
data.creationtime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.creationtime);
data.modificationtime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.modificationtime);
```

i am not sure how to do it because i have two identical lines , can some one please guide me ?

i have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164453/how-can-one-search-and-replace-2-lines-together-via-eclipse) but regex patterns is not working

**SOLUTION**

I have tried below pattern and it worked

For Match :-
 `(data.creationtime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer\(data.creationtime\);\s*?data.)([^ ]+?)( = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer\(*?data.)([^ ]+?)(\);)`

For Replace :-   `$1modificationtime$3modificationtime$5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most efficient way, but it should work.

**Search-Pattern:**

```
(data.creationtime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer\(data.creationtime\);\s*?data.)([^ ]+?)( = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer\(data.creationtime\);)
```

**Replacement-Pattern:**

```
$1modificationtime$3
```

**Demo:**
https://www.myregextester.com/?r=da9d3e48

Comment: eclipse takes only one line at a time in search field how to specify above pattern in single line.

Comment: By using * (multiple) \s (whtiespace metachars) in ? (lazy) mode, you can capture the linebreak. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Could you send me some more lines of the input data to pastebin.com ? Then I can test better in Eclipse.

Comment: Hm... the above Regex works for me. Just use the simple Search&Replace dialog (Ctrl+F) and check "Regex". http://i.imgur.com/rKAhZO9.png

Comment: Yes it working fine for me as well, but its not replacing last creationtime to modification time `DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.modificationtime);`

Comment: I have tried below pattern and it worked 
For Match :-   `(data.creationtime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer\(data.creationtime\);\s*?data.)([^ ]+?)( = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer\(*?data.)([^ ]+?)(\);)`
For Replace :-   `$1modificationtime$3modificationtime$5`