# Remove multiple lines in a set of classes

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse, I need to remove 4 lines of code from 473 classes. I know how to search files with regexp, but not for multiple lines. If Eclipse can't do this, another tool is fine.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This seems to be described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164453/how-to-search-and-replace-2-lines-together-in-eclipse and there is an old feature request in the eclipse bug database with a similar solution at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26780  - Basically use copy/paste combined with the regular expression feature of the file search/replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expression match the searched lines so that they can be replaced with an empty string to delete them:

```
(?<=[\r\n])[ \t]*+(?:(?:private|static)\s++){2}([\w_$]++)\s++([\w_$]++)\s*+=\s*+new\s++\1\(\)\s*+;\s*+(?:(?:public|static)\s++){2}\1\s++getInstance\(\)\s*+\{\s*+return\s*+\2\s*+;\s*+\}[ \r]*+[\r\n]*+
```

Comment: Amazing, it works! Unfortunately I've discovered that I can't remove these lines :-(